# Getting a PS3 for Ratchet & Clank Future. What about PSN?

Tags: psn

My brother plans to get a PlayStation 3, and I get to play on it. That means I'll finally (!) be able to play the Ratchet & Clank Future series.

[In the wake of the recent attack on PSN](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21580/as-a-ps3-gamer-what-can-i-expect-in-the-aftermath-of-the-psn-security-breach-and), I'm now rather cautious about getting a PS3, more so than I want to be. But in any case, what do I need to know or be wary about regarding PSN, specifically for the new Ratchet games? Even basic questions like "do I need an account for these games in the first place?" would be good for an answer, because I can't really find much info addressing that. I'm equally interested in what I'd be missing out on if I stay offline, though.

I know that demos are available on PSN, but since I'll be buying the games anyway I probably don't need them. I'll also be going to the store and buy the games from there, instead of purchasing online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play games without signing up to PSN then you will not be able to download any patches or updates for the games. This would mean missing out on additional features added after the game was released, and of course any bug fixes. How important this is depends on the game, as some games get a lot more post-release support than others.

Comment: IIRC, none of the R&CF games got post-release updates.  But for other games, they have been crucial!

Comment: (At the time I posted that comment, Insomniac's site was down, but it should be back up soon.)

Comment: On a side note, the first time I launched A Crack in Time, PSN told me there was an update available for it.

Comment: You can download patches even when sigend out of PSN, for example, on downtimes

Answer (score 1):

While you don't need a PSN account to play Tools of Destruction or A Crack in Time (the first and third R&CF games), the second game (Quest for Booty) is only available via download from the PSN.  (At least, in North America; I recall hearing that it was available on disc in Europe.)  **Edit:** [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_%26_Clank#Ratchet_.26_Clank_Future:_Quest_for_Booty), Quest for Booty was released on Blu-Ray in Europe and Asia.

A Crack in Time supports trophies (equivalent to achievements), which I believe are only reported if you have a PSN account.  They should still be tracked locally even without one, however.

Comment: I live in Singapore. I'll see if Q4B stocks here. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: I hope you find it!  It was the reason I originally signed up for a PSN account… and therefore the reason my info is presumably now in the hands of criminals.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

The newest game in the Series **Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One** is playable without going online, but the main attraction is being able to play with up to 3 friends split screen AND online in any possible combination you like.

Comment: Just a little tidbit: A4O is not part of the Future trilogy; however since it's one of the PS3 games this is still useful to know. +1

Comment: True enough. I picked it up last night, but due to working on my halloween costume haven't even really looked at it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Single player games do not require a PSN account. You can just play without it, and it should not affect gameplay in any way.

Comment: Anything I'll miss out on without it? (Just edited this into my question.)

Comment: If there's trophies, then you won't get to show them off to friends. That's about it really.